# ASP.net MVC6 Tag Helpers generating invalid markup?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, tag-helpers

Consider the following:

```
<link asp-fallback-href="~/vendor/lightbox2/css/lightbox.min.css"
      asp-fallback-test-class="lightbox"
      asp-fallback-test-property="position"
      asp-fallback-test-value="absolute"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.8.2/css/lightbox.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" />
```

The following meta tag is generated by asp:

```
<meta name="x-stylesheet-fallback-test" class="lightbox" />
```

If I try and validate this using the HTML5 validator I receive the following error:

Validator.nu (Public): Element “meta” is missing one or more of the following attributes: “content”, “property”.

Is there anyway I can resolve this issue or should I report this to the asp team?

**Update**

I've submitted this as an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3449) to the asp.net team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be by design, according to [the issue that details the requirements](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1580):

> The failure is determined by way of injecting a dummy `<meta>` tag with a specified class name (`asp-fallback-test-class` attribute) and then testing the computed style of that element to see if a specified CSS property (`asp-fallback-test-property` attribute) is equal to a specified value (`asp-fallback-test-value`).

[The HTML 5.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-meta-element) *(warning: large document)* has the following to say:

> Exactly one of the `name`, `http-equiv`, `charset`, and `itemprop` attributes must be specified.
>
> If either `name`, `http-equiv`, or `itemprop` is specified, then the `content` attribute must also be specified. Otherwise, it must be omitted.

So this seems to be a bug. As you may have noticed in the bug report you submitted, the issue [has been fixed](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3449) for RC2.